# How do I find spectral arrows in Survival mode and in the Creative inventory?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-education-edition

I just learned about something called Spectral Arrows from searching online about arrows, but somehow, I just can't find Spectral Arrows in Creative Inventory for Minecraft Java and Minecraft Edu. Bonus: If there are Spectral Arrows, how do we get them in Survival Mode?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are three ways of getting spectral arrows (in Survival):

- You can craft them using 4 glowstone dust and a single arrow
- You can find them in bastion remnant chests, or
- You can try your luck and barter with piglins.

Comment: What mode do you use, or is it open to all versions?

Comment: It is on the Java Edition of Minecraft. It was added in the **1.9 Combat Update**. For more information, visit the wiki fandom site: https://minecraft.fandom.com/wiki/Arrow